# How to get the length of an array?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012, axapta

How to get the length of a string array like

```
str 30 name[];//dynamic array
```

I used the following for getting the length,but it showing the error as "the variable is not of the type CLASS."

```
int len=name.get_length();
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might be happier using the `Array` **collection class**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/array.aspx

```
static void TestArray(Args _args)
{
    Array   strArray = new Array(Types::String);
    ;

    strArray.value(1, 'abc');
    strArray.value(2, 'def');

    info(strfmt("%1", strArray.lastIndex()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `dimOf` function. Take a look to the reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa597117.aspx

Comment: thanks ..but we cant able to get the length of string array using dimOf. I tried with dimOf function.its nt working with string array.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is no build-in function to return the string array size. Since you are in full control what you put in the array, there need not be any!

The built-in function `dimof` returns the allocated size of the array, which is only of practical value for a fixed size array like `str 30 name[20]`, where `dimof(name)` returns 20.

A clean way to remain in control, is to use a setter function:

```
static void TestArray(Args _args)
{
    str 30 name[];
    int n = 0;
    int i;
    void nameSet(int _i, str 30 _name)
    {
        n = max(n,_i);
        name[_i] = _name;
    }
    ;
    nameSet(2,'abc');
    nameSet(4,'def');
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        info(name[i]);
}
```

There is no upper bound index limit, so accessing `name[7]` is perfectly valid and in this case returns a blank value. This may be used to your advantage, if you always use all holes and never stores a blank:

```
static void TestArray(Args _args)
{
    str 30 name[];
    int i;
    name[1] = 'abc';
    name[2] = 'def';
    for (i = 1; name[i]; i++)
        info(name[i]);
}
```

Beware that accessing a higher index (in this case higher than 2) may in fact increase the allocated size of the array.